# What are the naming rules for CIL Classes and Methods

Tags: c#, .net, naming, cil

And how do they differ from C#?

Is there any standard way of writing a name for a method in CIL that can not conflict with any C# method, as the CIL name is illegal in C#?

Could such a name cause issues with other .net languages such as F# or Visual Basic?

An example of a naming rule in C# is: `Method2` is a legal name for a method in C#, but `2Method` is an illegal method name since names cannot start with a digit, but may contain digits. What naming rules are there for CIL?

I'm writing an auto-generated method that is only used by Il, and I want to make sure it doesn't conflict with any C# name.

Comment: The CLR accepts almost anything.  Formally the set of characters specified in Unicode TR15, annex 7, using normalization rule C.  It has to, given that it must support the naming rules of any language that runs on it.  Notably ab/used pretty heavily by obfuscators, they'll use non-printable characters to make it hard.  So it is not the rock that you need to look under, go by what the language specifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write code that can interop with any .NET Language you follow the guidelines of the Common Language Specification, and ensure that your publicly-visible types are "CLS Compliant":

> To fully interact with other objects written in any language, objects
>   must expose to callers only those features that are common to all
>   languages. This common set of features is defined by the Common
>   Language Specification (CLS), which is a set of rules that apply to
>   generated assemblies. The Common Language Specification is defined in
>   Partition I, Clauses 7 through 11 of the [ECMA-335 Standard: Common
>   Language Infrastructure](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).

[Language Independence and Language-Independent Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/language-independence-and-language-independent-components)

Comment: Actually I'm looking for the opposite: I'm writing an auto-generated method that is only used by Il, and I want to make sure it doesn't conflict with any C# name.

Comment: You'll need to review the rules for identifiers in C# here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure  You've already identified a simple pattern for generating illegal-in-C# identifiers.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you actually mean CLS compliance. This is detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/language-independence-and-language-independent-components) along with the naming rules. The most important thing seems to be to make sure that two identifiers differ in more than just case.